# jQuery UI autocomplete get response back from php script

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I'm trying to imitate this example: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple-remote

Here's are two of the target elements:

```
<input size="50" class="attr_values" name="collection" id="collection" />
<input size="50" class="attr_values" name="color" id="color" />
```

They send the "term" (search term the user types in) and the "attr_name" (e.g. collection or color) to a php script. Now I'm trying to figure out how to target the response data to the right input id.

Here's my version of the script. I've attached `.autocomplete` to the `attr_values` class, and there are many instances of it on the page. So, in the source section, I added one element to the JSON array to send the `id` to the php script.

Now I need to figure out the other side of it. How do I target the response to the correct text box? I cannot figure out what `response` is doing.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // 2 string parsing functions
    function split( val ) {
        return val.split( /,\s*/ );
    }
    function extractLast( term ) {
        return split( term ).pop();
    }


    $( '.attr_values' )
        // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
        .bind( 'keydown', function( event ) {
            if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                    $( this ).data( 'autocomplete' ).menu.active ) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        })
        .autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                $.getJSON( 'controllers/core_data/ajax/core_data.php', {
                    'attr_name' : this.element[0].id,
                    'term': extractLast( request.term )
                }, response );
            },
            search: function() {
                // custom minLength
                var term = extractLast( this.value );
                if ( term.length < 2 ) {
                    return false;
                }
            },
            focus: function() {
                // prevent value inserted on focus
                return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                var terms = split( this.value );
                // remove the current input
                terms.pop();
                // add the selected item
                terms.push( ui.item.value );
                // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                terms.push( '' );
                this.value = terms.join( ', ' );
                return false;
            }
        });

 });
```

EDIT:
To test the PHP script, right now I just have it doing this:

```
echo "[ 'foo','barf','mr T' ]";
```

SOLUTION:

I changed the above to:

```
echo '[ "foo","barf","mr T" ]';
```

And now it works. Very strange, I did not think quotes mattered in JSON.

Comment: What does the php script return?

Comment: @Asad currently it is just returning an array, irrespective of input. The biggest problem I thinkis targeting the correct field id.

Comment: @TahirYasin what's your point?

Comment: @ButtleButkus Well those are the suggestions you should be getting. Are you not getting any suggestions?

Comment: @Asad no I was not getting any. Thank you for your hint. The real answer seems to be the use of single quotes and double quotes though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `response` argument is a callback that you are simply meant to invoke with the final array of suggestions as an argument.

So if I wanted to make an autocomplete that always suggests "red", "green" and "blue", I would make my `source` function look like this:

```
source: function( request, response ) {
    response(["red", "green", "blue"]);
},
```

Assuming your PHP script returns an array of string values notated in JSON, what you are doing should work.

The reason your PHP output was causing problems was that JSON uses *double* quotes as delimiters, not single quotes. `['foo','barf','mr T']` is invalid JSON.

Comment: Asad, thank you so much for that hint. Hard-coding the response into the jquery does function correctly, adding elements to the right box. But the data from the PHP script doesn't come show up. Any ideas why?

Comment: This seems to be the reason and it's very weird: this doesn't work: echo "[ 'foo','barf','mr T' ]"; but this works: echo '[ "foo","barf","mr T" ]';

Comment: @ButtleButkus JSON uses double quotes as delimiters, so `['foo','barf','mr T']` probably isn't valid JSON.

Comment: @ButtleButkus To see what I mean, try: `JSON.parse("['foo','barf','mr T']");`

Comment: thanks. It makes sense, but I swear I used both quote systems with no problem a few months ago, but I think it was on the client side, not with server side returning values to the client.

Comment: @ButtleButkus In JS you can use both, i.e. `var x = ['foo', 'bar']` and `var x = ["foo", "bar"]` are both fine. It's just that the first one isn't valid JSON, so it can't be parsed as JSON.